# filter expected 2 arguments, got 1 with lambda

Tags: python, lambda

I am trying to learn more about lambda functions in Python. I want to get a list of only those numbers from `my_list` that are divisible by an user-input number `a`. This is what I have done:

```
my_list = [11, 12, 15, 3, 6, 33, 58]
a = int(input("Enter number by which we'll divide: "))
divs = list(filter(lambda x,a:(x%a == 0, my_list, a)))
print("Divisible numbers are: ", divs)
```

Unfortunately I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: filter expected 2 arguments, got 1
```

Comment: Show code, output and error messages as properly formatted text in the question, not as image or external link.

Comment: `divs = list(filter(lambda x: x%a==0, my_list))`.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "lambda function". A lambda *expression* is just an expression that produces a `function` object, the same kind of object produced by a `def` statement.

Comment: `filter`'s first argument should be a function that takes exactly *one* argument and returns a `bool`. `filter` will apply that to each element of its second argument in order to determine which of those elements to include in its own result.

Comment: Understand what the error is telling you: `filter()` wants 2 arguments. You did `filter(lambda x,a:(x%a == 0, my_list, a))`. `lambda x, a: (x % a == 0, mylist, a)` is your lambda which takes _two_ arguments, and returns a tuple containing the result of `x % a`, the list `my_list`, and the integer `a`. This is the only argument you give to `filter()`. Read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) for `filter()` carefully to understand exactly what it wants

Answer (score 0):

Ignore lambda expressions for the moment. How would you write this using a `def` statement?

```
a = int(input(...))


def divisible_by_a(x):
    return x % a == 0


divs = list(filter(divisible_by_a, my_list))
```

The corresponding lambda expression for the function defined by the `def` statement is just `lambda x: x % a == 0`.

```
divs = list(filter(lambda x: x % a == 0, my_list))
```

In both cases, the function used by `filter` relies on `a` being defined in the calling scope, as it is a free variable inside that function, not a parameter.

---

In this case, a list comprehension would be simpler and more efficient, as it won't involve any user-defined functions (whether from a `def` statement or a lambda expression):

```
divs = [x for x in my_list if x % a == 0]
```